# Instalação de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

É possível fazer a instalação do **Laravel** em qualquer hospedagem compartilhada? 
Ou os requisitos necessários para instalação são muito específicos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#install-laravel) basta ter a versão `5.3.7`  do php e a extensão `MCrypt` habilitada.

> The Laravel framework has a few system requirements:
>
> PHP >= 5.3.7
>
> MCrypt PHP Extension
>
> As of PHP 5.5, some OS distributions may require you to manually
>   install the PHP JSON extension. When using Ubuntu, this can be done
>   via apt-get install php5-json.

Comment: Apenas para complementar, se eu estiver correto, basta eu levar o código todo da minha máquina para o servidor, se ele tem o suporte devido irá rodar.

Comment: Vc pode verificar as configurações do servidor, criando um arquivo php, com esse código `<?php phpinfo()` veja se versão é a 5.3.7 e se o Mcrypt está habilitado e deve funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

### Sim, é possível.

No momento, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Laravel 4, e o cliente me forneceu acesso a hospedagem compartilhada no "HostGator".

Tive que habilitar a versão correta do PHP no provedor (a versão *default* é a 5.2) - isto foi feito via `.htaccess`

Eu estou desenvolvendo localmente usando **Git** e **Composer**, normalmente. Criei um repositório Git no plano *free* do **Beanstalk** (e dei o nome pro *remote* local de "beanstalk"), e configurei lá um *deploy* automático via FTP.

Localmente, crei um *branch* chamado "deploy", onde removi o diretório `vendor` do `.gitignore`, para que as pastas em `vendor` entrem no repositório.

Então, após testar bem meu código, e fazer o *commit*, com um simples comando...

```
git push beanstalk deploy
```

...eis que:

- mantenho um repositório remoto atualizado,
- e tenho o *site* atualizado automaticamente.

O *deploy* do Beanstalk faz o *upload* dos arquivos modificados, automaticamente, via FTP. Jóia!

Comment: J. Bruni você poderia informar qual comando você utilizou no .htaccess e em qual diretorio você o deixou para habilitar o PHP no servidor? Estou tendo um problema que quando utilizo o PHP 5.5 ele le o php.ini do diretorio padrão e não o que eu posso configurar(/home/cpaneluser/php.ini)

Answer (score -2):

Você pode fazer a instalação do Laravel em qualquer máquina usando o comando:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

Se o `composer` não estiver disponível globalmente, você pode baixá-lo na pasta atual para fazer a instalação pelo `composer.phar`, assim:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Ou, no caso de você não ter o `curl`:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

Se ainda assim você não conseguir fazer a instalação, você pode desenvolver na sua máquina local e fazer o *deploy* em outra máquina por meio do Capifony (que pode transferir os arquivos via `rsync`), por exemplo.